# Show if set is countable or uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that the infinite set of all words, meaningful or not, of any finite length, made with the 26 letters of the English alphabet is uncountable.

I believe the answer to be no but I am stuck trying to prove that one of the subsets is uncountable and thus the full set is too. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the set is countable. Let's replace the alphabet with the set of numbers $B=\{0,1, 2, 3, ..., 25\}$ - this has the same number of elements, so the problem is the same.

Now, given a string $\sigma=b_1b_2...b_n$ from $B$, consider the number $$1b_1b_2...b_n$$ where the $b_i$s are interpreted as base-$26$ digits; e.g. the string "$22$" gets sent to the base-$26$ number "$122$", or in base $10$ the number $$1\cdot 26^2+2\cdot 26+2=676+52+26=754.$$

This process of taking a *string* and outputting a *number* gives an injection from the set of finite strings of symbols in $B$, to the natural numbers; hence the set of finite strings of symbols in $B$ is countable.

*We put "$1$" at the front to make sure that the map is injective - e.g. otherwise the strings "$034$" and "$34$" both yield the same number, whereas $1034$ and $134$ are very different numbers.*

---

More generally, by the same trick the set of finite strings of symbols in $X$ for *any* finite $X$ is countable. And in fact more is true - as long as $X$ is *countable*, the set of finite strings of symbols in $X$ is countable, although this takes a bit more work to show (show that $(i)$ any finite power of a countable set is countable and $(ii)$ the union of countably many countable sets is countable (this is really implicit in $(i)$ - take the power to be $2$). Now the set of finite strings of symbols in $X$ can be decomposed into the sets of strings of length $n$, as $n$ varies through the naturals. Each of these sets is countable by $(i)$, and so by $(ii)$ the union of them all is countable.

---

By contrast, everything goes to heck if we look at *infinite* sequences instead. If $X$ has more than one element, then the set of infinite strings of symbols in $X$ is always uncountable. This is due to [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_diagonal_argument), and shows that we have to be very careful when thinking about infinity to distinguish between *finite* and *infinite* strings, sets, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This set will be countable. Let $A$ be the set of 26 letters and $A^n$ be the set of words with $n$ letters, then $A^n$ is finite. Then your infinite set of all words is the union of the sets of words with length $n$:
$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A^n$$
hence a countable union of finite sets, hence countable.